# Photodisintegration vs Spallation

Tags: nucleosynthesis

Is photodisintegration belongs to a form of spallation? Is photodisintegration only limited to nucleus hit by high energy gamma-ray, whereas the nucleus in spallation can be hit by any ​high energy particles?

Comment: I would not use spallation to refer to a photon interacting with a nucleus. May depend on usage in various subfields - for example I would use photofission, not photodisintegration, perhaps another subfield distinction.

Comment: @JonCuster both [photodisintegration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photodisintegration) and [Photofission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photofission) seem to have Wikipedia pages and the distinction seems to be on what the outcome is; if it's light particle emission like a nucleon or alpha particle then it's the former. If what happens can be characterized as [nuclear fission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fission) (which has it's own lower mass limit ambiguity), then it's the latter.

Comment: @uhoh - and the terminology seems to have drifted or simplified. Going back to the 1950's, articles specified photoprotons or photoneutrons or photodeuterons depending on what came out.

Comment: @JonCuster you regularly out-earliest-applicable-reference me, *kudos!*